# Can't set Windows XP background

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-customization

I have a Windows XP (Home) machine with a very weird problem. I cannot set the background image properly. That is, I can go to Desktop, Background image, select a different one, but the background has still the same solid colour. Now if I kill `explorer.exe`, I can see the background image correctly, but starting `explorer.exe` gives me the solid colour background back again.

If I go to Desktop, Customise Desktop, Web, there is a checkbox at the bottom called "Fix desktop icons" or something like this (not sure how it's called in the English version.) If I *enable* this checkbox, I can see the background, but the desktop icons are drawn with solid-colour backgrounds (even though I have the "draw icon labels transparently" option set.) If I *disable* the checkbox, I have no desktop background. Active Desktop is *disabled*.

Any idea how to fix this and what might be the reason for this behaviour in the first place?

Comment: Drivers are up to date?

Comment: Graphics driver software might be overriding Windows with its own background specification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the same dialog box that you mentioned about the "fix desktop icons" button, ensure that **active desktop** isn't enabled by unchecking everything in the list.

[image]

Next, go into the Registry Editor and check that there is not a key called **'NoChangingWallpaper'** in either of the following locations.  If there is, delete it and restart.

1. Click Start
2. Click `Run`
3. Type `regedit`
4. Click `OK`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop`
and
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop`

Try **resetting the Windows theme**:

1. Right-click your desktop
2. Click `Properties`
3. Click the `Themes` tab
4. Select `Windows XP` from the list of themes
5. Click `Apply`
6. Restart your computer

[image]

Failing that, try an **sfc /scannow** to check for any corrupt system files they may be preventing the desktop wallpaper from automatically refreshing.

1. Pop in your XP installation media and cancel out of the installation wizard
2. Click Start
3. Click `Run`
4. Type `sfc /scannow`
5. Click `OK`
6. When the box disappears, restart your computer

[image]

If this does not work, try a [**system restore**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084).

Answer (score 0):

how about deleting a file from the registry that is restricting it.

Comment: I'd be a little more inclined to upvote this if you gave a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Control Panel > Accessibility Options > Display > CHECK "Use High Contrast" box > APPLY
2. UNCHECK "Use High Contrast" box > APPLY

Worked for me.
Registry fixes did not.